# How to Hide Expansion Gap around Oven

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, trim, cabinets

I'm getting ready to float a bamboo floor in my kitchen. I know I need to lay the flooring underneath the appliances, and I'll need to leave an expansion gap next to the cabinets and walls. The trouble is that there's not really much room between the cabinets (about 30" apart, which seems standard?) and the oven.

More or less everywhere else, I've been adding a quarter round to the baseboards to help keep that gap covered. I should be able to do that with the refrigerator and perhaps the dishwasher, but I suspect it won't fit around the oven. The gap is about half an inch, and the quarter round that matches the cabinets is 3/4" on both flat sides. Is there another way to cover the gap? Do quarter rounds typically fit, with this being a bit too tight a squeeze?

Closeup image of gap, which is about half an inch:
[image: Closeup of gap]

Comment: Shave 1/4 inch off the two bits of 1/4 round next to the oven. Are the mice prone to complaining about the quality of the woodwork in there? Nobody else sees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base shoe is more common these days, partly for this reason. It's only about 1/2" deep, and generally fits alongside appliances without a problem. Still, I'd bet 3/4" quarter will fit along and under the fridge body from what I can see here.

Worst case scenario you may need to lift your appliances slightly using a rear wheel shim and the front adjusters.